# Where should I ask the question in which I need feedback or comments?

Tags: discussion

I want to post a question to get some expert feedback of community members.

It is related to comparison between Magento and one another e commerce platform.

Where should I ask this question or in which board as it will not be coding related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento StackExchange is not limited to questions about coding, but as you phrase it, it might be closed as "primary opinion based". Questions like "What is better, X or Y?" are not suited for the StackExchange Q&A format.

If you have a specific question that can be answered in an objective manner, go ahead and ask. If not, it might have a chance on Meta because the rules are not so strict here but even if it's not going to be closed, I don't expect it to be very well perceived.

For discussion and gathering opinions, try http://www.reddit.com/r/magento or the official Magento forums at http://community.magento.com/ instead.